# Adding files (*.xls) to android project

Tags: android

What folder should I put in excel files (*.xls) to android project? I want them to be in the apk files, and how to open them later? I tried to put them in assets folder, and open like that:

```
    try {
        in = getAssets().open("schedule.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "can't open the file";
    }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: in = getResources().getAssets().open("schedule.xls");
works just great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in = getResources().getAssets().open("schedule.xls");
```

This works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `xls` or `xml`? These are two very different types, make sure you're using the right file type.

Any file can be put in `res/raw` folder. If the folder doesn't exist create it.